# Dynamic Reconfigure to camera.yaml file?

Tags: ros, camera-drivers, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to use the Dynamic Reconfigure GUI to configure my camera (bayer settings, etc.) and then publish that information to a camera.yaml file.  I don't see anything about how to do this in either the camera_drivers or dynamic_reconfigure tutorials, and I don't really know how to get started.  Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10266/dynamic-reconfigure-to-camera.yaml-file?/) by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 422 on 2011-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Bradley,

Once you have the settings the way you want, go to another terminal window, move to the directory where you want to save your camera.yaml file (e.g. roscd my_package/params), then issue the command:

$ rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam dump /camera_node_name camera.yaml

where /camera_node_name is the name of the node you are configuring in dynamic_reconfigure.

To load this file from a launch file at a later time, add the following to the launch file:

```
<node name="dynamic_reconfigure_load" pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="dynparam" args="load /camera_node_name $(find my_package)/params/camera.yaml" />
```

where of course you need to make the appropriate substitutions for /camera_node_name and the package location of your camera.yaml file.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-06-15**:
Awesome--glad to help!

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-06-15**:
Excellent.  Works great, and a very quick turnaround.  Thank you!